# How to submit multiple forms at the same time

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have two forms which are working fine with a little problem where I cannot figure out.

Both forms are submitting data but when I submit the item's to cart it does update or insert the quantity what I have updated for item one, if you choose a different quantity for any other item and add it will insert the quantity of the first item only not the selected  items quantity.

**Javascript code for multiple form submission**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
submitForms = function(){
    document.forms["quantity"].submit();
    document.forms["submit"].submit();
}
</script>
```

**Form # 1 Quantity**

```
<form class="" id="<?php echo $mitem_ida; ?>" name="quantity" action="item_process.php" method="post" target="votar">
<div class="quantity-wrap">
<div class="quantity" style="margin-bottom: -12px;">
<input type="button" value="-" onclick="javascript: subtractQtyz('<?php echo $mitem_ida; ?>');" >
<input name="qtyz" type="number" readonly class="qty" id="quantityx_<?php echo $mitem_ida; ?>" value="1" />
<input type="button" value="+" onclick="javascript: document.getElementById('quantityx_<?php echo $mitem_ida; ?>').value++;">
<font style="color: black; text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #999999;">كمية</font>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

**Form # 2 other fields**

```
<form class="formItem" id="<?php echo $mitem_ida; ?>" name="quantity" action="item_process.php" method="post" target="votar">
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $mitem_ida; ?>" name="item_id">
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $mitem_pricea; ?>" name="price_id">

<?php if ($detect->isMobile()) { ?>
  <div class="item-price" style="background-color: green; margin-top:-35px; margin-left: 105px;">
<?php }else{ ?>
  <div class="item-price" style="background-color: green; margin-top:-92px; margin-left: 105px;">
<?php } ?>                              
<span class="amount">

<a style="color: white;" href="#" onclick="submitForms()" >
<font style="font-size: 12px;">
<?php if ($lang == 'en') {
echo "Add To Cart";
}else{
echo "<b>أضف إلى السلة</b>";
}
?>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</font>
</a>
</span>
</div></form>
```

**php mysql query**

```
if (isset($_SESSION['ses_user_id']) == true){
$ses_mem        =   $_SESSION['ses_user_id'];
}else{
$ses_mem    =   session_id();
}

$insitID    =   mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['item_id']); // 2nd form
$inspr      =   mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['item_price']); // 2nd form
$iqty       =   mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['qtyz']); //1st form

mysql_query("
insert into temp_cart (item_id, price_id, ses_mem, qty) values (
'".$insitID."','".$inspr."','".$ses_mem."','".$iqty."'
)
");
```

Comment: you can't submit two forms at some time, you should do this using ajax or something else...

Answer (score 1):

Calling **submit** function will trigger a full page reload, hence the second call to **submit** will never be executed (check it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_form_submit), it reloads the iframe).

To submit both forms without losing data you should use AJAX. Either [natively](https://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_ajax_database.asp) or using a framework like [jQuery](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_post.asp)